# JQuery .text() cannot use indexOf to find spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is an odd one.

I have a list item, containing the text '13 May 2011'. I have a lot of these dates, and I want to use JQuery to search them by a free text input (they're not always dates), but I can't seem to search for anything if I put a space in the search box.

However,

```
li.text() // 13 May 2011
li.text().indexOf('13') // 0
li.text().indexOf('13 ') // -1
li.text().indexOf(' ') // -1
'13 May 2011'.indexOf('13') // 0
'13 May 2011'.indexOf('13 ') // 0
li.text() == '13 May 2011' // false
```

I've pasted my return text into a text-to-hex converter, and the space character is a '20' (32 in decimal, which is a space in ASCII), so it's not a funny space character.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Interestingly, the results I get in Chrome are: `"13 May 2011", 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, true`. You can [see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/XXUhp/).

Comment: @Connell what browser are you using to test with?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 12's console to get them results. I'm just about to test in Firefox 4

Comment: I'm using Chrome 12, and it works for me: http://jsbin.com/asaki4/2/edit

Comment: Here is what i get: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/HTdzB/  (Chrome 12)  results: `13 May 2011 0 0 2 0 0 true`

Comment: @Chris it must be the way I load the data from the database then. Maybe other whitespace characters. I'll find a Javascript function to get hex from a string and do li.text().toHex() or something, I'll let you know.

Comment: Firefox 3 shows the same results as Connell. There must be something happening to the text before it's put into the <li>, if you test it with a plain `<li id="li">13 May 2011</li>` your code seems to work properly

Comment: The fiddle results in `"13 May 2011" "13 May 2011" 13 May 2011 0 0 2 0 0 true` for me.

Comment: Yup. Those pastes all seem to work the same for me too (why didn't I try this before?!). I'll let you know how this hex thing goes when I get it done.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Chris 1.6.1... I've just got a hex function up and `hex(li.text())` returns `31 33 a0 4d 61 79 a0 32 30 31 31`.. so my so called space is an `a4` character!

Comment: Because I assumed it'd be some sort of whitespace, which could possibly be more than one ASCII char (such as carriage return and new line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question. Thanks to all those that helped me along the way by leaving comments!

All tests with this list item have worked as they should except the real version on my machine! For some reason, it's not a space, it's ASCII character 160 (a non-breaking space, HTML entity `&nbsp;`)

Further investigation shows

```
hex(li.text()) // 31 33 a0 4d 61 79 a0 32 30 31 31
li.text().indexOf('13'+String.fromCharCode(160)) // 0
```

I'm not going to question why, at least it works now :D